# The second main if(empty($ureciver )) statement does not execute at all..what am i missing

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm working on a two table mysql database with tables p and g.
Here I'm trying to check if the value of a variable $ureciever returned from a select query on table 'p' is empty or not and based on that update two different columns 'partner1' and 'partner2' on table 'g' with the session username variable.  Only one of 'partner1' and 'partner2' should be updated in one iteration of the code.

```
if(empty($ureciever) ) {
        {       
$query ="UPDATE g
        SET partner1= '".$_SESSION['username']."'
        WHERE packageg = '$upackage' AND banned = 0 AND  partner1 =''
        ORDER BY useridg ASC
        LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_affected_rows($conn);
    }
if($count == 1){
    $countdown = time() + 648000;
$query = "UPDATE p AS p
    JOIN g  AS g ON  p.username = g.partner1
    SET p.reciever = g.usernameg, p.time_expires = '$countdown'
    WHERE p.username ='".$_SESSION["username"]."'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count1 = mysql_affected_rows($conn);
}
```

The above code section executes properly, however the alternate code which should run if the condition being tested is false  simply fails to run. I've checked my brackets, semi colons, recoded the test condition to no positive effect.   This is the section giving me problems below.

```
else if($count != 1){

    $query= "UPDATE g
        SET partner2 = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
        WHERE packageg = '$package' AND banned = 0 AND  partner2 =''
        ORDER BY useridg ASC
        LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysql_query($query);
$count2 = mysql_affected_rows($conn);
}
if ($count2 == 1)

    {
        $countdown = time() + 648000;
$query = "UPDATE p AS p
        JOIN g  AS g ON  p.username = g.partner2
        SET p.reciever = g.usernameg, p.time_expires = '$countdown'
        WHERE p.username ='".$_SESSION["username"]."'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count1 = mysql_affected_rows($conn);
        }
}

else{

$_SESSION['paired'] = "You  have been matched to pay someone. Please be quick";
        }
```

Comment: empty return true or false ... your condition 0  or 1 ==  " " never return true use empty($var) || $var == " "

Comment: first of all this statement if(empty($ureciever)== ' ' ) is wrong do not have to check with ' ' empty itself check it make it correct to if(empty($ureciever) )

Answer (score 1):

`empty($ureciever)` would return boolean. So `TRUE`/`FALSE` `!=` `' '`.

No need to check `empty($ureciever)== ' '`. So the code should be -

```
if(empty($ureciever)) {
    ......
}
```

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: You are right. I've been messing with the code for some hours now, making tweaks that I feel could have an effect on the code. I've changed that back.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i finally figured it out. The problem was coming from my use of $upackage variable. Compare the correct form in the section immediately below to the inadvertent use of $package in the second/last code section

```
$query ="UPDATE g
        SET partner1= '".$_SESSION['username']."'
        WHERE packageg = **'$upackage'** AND banned = 0 AND  partner1 =''
        ORDER BY useridg ASC
        LIMIT 1";
```

Sometimes i guess we just need to step away from the problem and do something else, then come back with a new outlook. Problem solved!

```
 $query= "UPDATE g
        SET partner2 = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
        WHERE packageg = **'$package'** AND banned = 0 AND  partner2 =''
        ORDER BY useridg ASC
        LIMIT 1";
```